# Spring MVC project compilation warnings

Tags: spring-mvc, compiler-warnings

Everything compiles, but these warnings are displayed:

```
Warning: advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

Warning: advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

Warning: advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

Warning: advice defined in org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

Can someone explain what exactly they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an output from your compile time AspectJ weaving process - It is showing you which AspectJ advices have not been applied in your codebase.

To expand on this a little more - the Spring related aspects are normally defined in the `META-INF/aop.xml` file in spring-aspects.jar file, and these aspects are woven into your classes based on the pointcuts that match in your codebase, if some pointcut does not match up, for eg, you probably don't have any `@Async` annotations anywhere, then the advice does not get applied and you would see the message that `advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied`